# Xpath sum valubles from multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, sum

So i want to find the total screen time for movies where Star Wars is part of the movie name. Should return an integer number

//Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id='Lucasfilms']

```
  <Subsidiary id="Lucasfilms">

  <Movie>
    <Name lang="en">Star Wars: The Force Awakens</Name>
    <Year>2015</Year>
    <ScreenTime unit="minutes">135</ScreenTime>
    <Cast>
  <Movie>
    <Name lang="en">Star Wars: The Last Jedi</Name>
    <Year>2017</Year>
    <ScreenTime unit="minutes">152</ScreenTime>
    <Cast>
  <Movie>
    <Name lang="en">Solo: A Star Wars Story</Name>
    <Year>2018</Year>
    <ScreenTime unit="minutes">135</ScreenTime>
    <Cast>
```

I do know ur supposed to use sum, but i struggle to put it together. May someone please help me

Comment: you should provide a well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I constructed a well-formed XML based on my imagination. Here is a working sample for you.

**XML**

```
<Disney>
    <Subsidiaries>
        <Subsidiary id="Lucasfilms">
            <Movie>
                <Name lang="en">Star Wars: The Force Awakens</Name>
                <Year>2015</Year>
                <ScreenTime unit="minutes">135</ScreenTime>
            </Movie>
            <Movie>
                <Name lang="en">Star Wars: The Last Jedi</Name>
                <Year>2017</Year>
                <ScreenTime unit="minutes">152</ScreenTime>
            </Movie>
            <Movie>
                <Name lang="en">Solo: A Star Wars Story</Name>
                <Year>2018</Year>
                <ScreenTime unit="minutes">135</ScreenTime>
            </Movie>
        </Subsidiary>
    </Subsidiaries>
</Disney>
```

**XPath**

```
sum(/Disney/Subsidiaries/Subsidiary[@id='Lucasfilms']/Movie/ScreenTime/text())
```

**Outcome:**

```
422
```